# MySQL: can anyone explain about using = to select not null rows

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner MySQL user.
My teacher gave me a question to explain how this function works.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName=ColumnName
```

Then, the result shows the rows that contain values in that column. (The null value is not appear)
I have no idea about it. I do searching for answer but most of it is talking about using IS NOT NULL.

Comment: @SMA let me take a wild guess: name of a column

Comment: @Nattntwd if you want to select records that contain null, then `columname is null` the expression you are looking for. But I cannot really understand your question.

Comment: @SMA not, it should not because null does not even equal to null. See Gordon's answer below.

Comment: your teacher is a monkey.  This is a terrible technique.  The reason this monkey technique works is because the expression "x = y" is always false if either x or y is null.  x is not null is significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
WHERE ColumnName = ColumnName
```

is comparing two values from the same column.  This should be true in all cases, except when `ColumnName` contains a `NULL` value.  So, you can equivalently write this as:

```
WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL
```

This version is more understandable and the preferred way to write the logic.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much
Your answer helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ' = ' to select rows by checking  an empty column right ?

> If that's the case 
>   You can simply use the below code

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = ' '
```